# How to connect mic to computer

Tags: microphones, mac

I have a vintage EV-1750 cardioid Electret Condenser microphone (with internal battery power) with a hardwired ⅛" TS plug.  Output level is -43db at 1000Hz and 150 ohms unbalanced.  How do I, or what do I need to use this mic with my iMac running OS 10.11.5?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There exists something called 
*Griffin Technology iMic - The original USB Stereo Input and Output Audio Adapter*
which came into my posession, and I did some reading about it while trying to determine an asking price for sale.  These were absolutely necessary with older Macbook models, as the on-board sound hardware lacked ability to deal with mic inputs.  You can probably get by with just a properly-matching adapter`1`-- making sure your computer's needs get lined up with what the vintage mic is sending out-- then tweaking the levels on the computer.  But this external USB device `2` is said to be "high quality" as re sound, and actually comprises "a sound card" itself, so it can make things easier & possibly more dynamically modular as far as your overall environment.

```
1
```

[image: adapters]

```
2
```

[image: iMic]

Answer (score 0):

You need a 1/8 inch to stereo headphone converter. If there's a radioshack that still exists near you they should have it, otherwise guitar center or best buy.

Also you might find that if you plug it in it works just fine with the mono.

Comment: With the help of an audio interface you will be able to have better sound quality and you will not have to get a converter.